# JavaFX, как обновлять Label и Progressbar во время выполнения метода?

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть статический метод загрузки файла:

```
public class Downloader {
    private static MainLayoutController mlController;
    private static int doneQuantity = 0;

    public static void setController(MainLayoutController c) {
        mlController = c;
    }

    public static void downloadFile(String url, String savePath, int buffSize) {
        try {
            /* Get connection */
            URL connection = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection urlconn;

            urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) connection.openConnection();
            urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconn.connect();

            /* Set input stream */
            InputStream in = null;

            in = urlconn.getInputStream();

            /* Find file full path */
            String[] tempArr = url.split("/");

            String fullPath = savePath + tempArr[tempArr.length - 1];

            /* Set Labels */
            //mlController.downloadingLabel.setText(tempArr[tempArr.length - 1]);
            //mlController.downloadedLabel.setText(doneQuantity + "/" + mlController.quantity);
            /*Task task = new Task() {
                @Override
                protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> updateTitle(tempArr[tempArr.length - 1]));

                    return 101;
                }
            };
            mlController.downloadingLabel.textProperty().bind(task.titleProperty());
            new Thread(task).start();*/

            /* Set write stream */
            OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(fullPath);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[buffSize]; // Max bytes per one reception

            /* Download */
            int i = 0;
            double getted_b = 0.0;
            long delta_t = System.nanoTime(), i_sum = 0;

            while ((i = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                getted_b += i;
                i_sum += i;

                writer.write(buffer, 0, i);

                if ((System.nanoTime() - delta_t) >= 1E9) { // If the second was over
                    int kb, mb;

                    mb = new Double(getted_b / (1024 * 1024)).intValue();
                    kb = new Double((getted_b / 1024) % 1024).intValue();

                    System.out.println(" >> Speed: " + mb + " " + kb + " Mb/sec");
                    System.out.println(" >> " + i_sum / (urlconn.getContentLength() / 100) + "%");

                    delta_t = System.nanoTime(); // Set to zero
                    getted_b = 0.0;
                }
            }

            /* Cleaning */
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Он получает доступ к `label`-ам и `progressbar`-ам через ссылку на класс-контроллер `mlController`. Мои безуспешные попытки обновлять лэйблы идут после комментария `/* Set Labels */`.
Подскажите, как лучше это делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная идея в том, что ваш метод downloadFile должен вызываться в отдельном потоке, а не в JavaFX Application Thread, а изменения элементов UI должны быть обернуты в  Platform.runLater(() -> { ... }).
Можно пойти дальше и сделать отдельный Task, который выполняет все работу, и имеет свойства message и progress, на которые можно забиндить метки.

```
public class App extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    VBox rootNode = new VBox();

    Label label = new Label();
    ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    Button button = new Button();

    button.setOnAction((e) -> {
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        label.textProperty().bind(downloadTask.messageProperty());
        progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(downloadTask.progressProperty());

        Thread th = new Thread(downloadTask);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
    });

    rootNode.getChildren().add(label);
    rootNode.getChildren().add(progressIndicator);
    rootNode.getChildren().add(button);

    Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 400, 200);
    stage.setTitle("App");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

class DownloadTask extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            updateMessage("Progress " + i);
            updateProgress(i, 100);

            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Тут есть проблема, если запускать `Task<>` с `updateProgress()` не из `FX Thread` выкинет исключение(не помню, какое точно, там сказано, что обновлять UI можно только из FX Thread). Причём, это не касается тасков с `updateMessage()`, они почему-то работают. Я сделал так: запустил загрузку в отдельном потоке(чтобы интерфейс не зависал во время загрузки больших файлов) и в метод загрузки добавил `Platform.runLater(() -> progressBarName.setProgress(x));`. Я всё это расписал, конечно, не для вас, а больше для таких как я) Вот ссылка на то что вышло: http://pastebin.com/JxcQyvE0

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, что вы думаете о коде по ссылке(http://pastebin.com/JxcQyvE0), как бы вы сделали и т.д.

Comment: Отвязался бы от необходимости передавать контроллер, перенес всю работу по скачиванию в Task. https://gist.github.com/russ-p/63d24c18fb9a702274df4e256d57c072 Еще стоило бы посмотреть  на javafx.concurrent.Service.